# Grouping data by 10 minutes using SUBSTR in DB2 leaves out a line of data?

Tags: sql, time, db2, grouping

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWKqI.png)

```
SELECT A.PRDDATE, A.PRDTIM || '000' AS PRDTIM,
    A.MACHCD, A.PRDCNT AS INPRDCNT, A.USEDWGT AS INUSEDWGT, ROUND(A.STDWGT,2) AS INSTDWGT, A.RATE*100 AS INRATE, A.PERWGT AS INPERWGT, ' ' AS INREMARK, B.PRDCNT AS OUTPRCNT, B.USEDWGT AS OUTUSEDWGT, ROUND(B.STDWGT,2) AS OUTSTDWGT, B.RATE*100 AS OUTRATE, B.PERWGT AS OUTPERWGT, ' ' AS OUTREMARK FROM (
    SELECT A.PRDDATE, SUBSTR(A.PRDTIME,1,3) AS PRDTIM, MAX(A.MACHCD) AS MACHCD,
    MIN(A.REFCNT) AS MINCNT, MAX(A.REFCNT) AS MAXCNT, DOUBLE(MAX(A.REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(A.REFCNT)) AS PRDCNT, DOUBLE(MIN(A.WEIGHT)) AS MINWGT, DOUBLE(MAX(A.WEIGHT)) AS MAXWGT, DOUBLE(MAX(A.WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(A.WEIGHT)) AS USEDWGT, DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(A.REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(A.REFCNT)))*0.02 AS STDWGT, ROUND((DOUBLE(MAX(A.WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(A.WEIGHT))-(DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(A.REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(A.REFCNT)))*0.02))/(DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(A.REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(A.REFCNT)))*0.02),2) AS RATE, ROUND((DOUBLE(MAX(WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(WEIGHT)))/(DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)))*1000,1) AS PERWGT FROM AGIF.POP3750 A WHERE WDATE = #{wdate} AND MACHCD = #{machcd} AND POSITION = 'I' GROUP BY A.PRDDATE,SUBSTR(A.PRDTIME,1,3) ORDER BY A.PRDDATE,SUBSTR(A.PRDTIME,1,3) ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT PRDDATE, SUBSTR(PRDTIME,1,3) AS PRDTIM,
    MAX(MACHCD) AS MACHCD,
    MIN(REFCNT) AS MINCNT, MAX(REFCNT) AS MAXCNT, DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)) AS PRDCNT, DOUBLE(MIN(WEIGHT)) AS MINWGT, DOUBLE(MAX(WEIGHT)) AS MAXWGT, DOUBLE(MAX(WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(WEIGHT)) AS USEDWGT, DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)))*0.011 AS STDWGT, ROUND((DOUBLE(MAX(WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(WEIGHT))-(DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)))*0.011))/(DOUBLE(DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)))*0.011),2) AS RATE, ROUND((DOUBLE(MAX(WEIGHT))-DOUBLE(MIN(WEIGHT)))/(DOUBLE(MAX(REFCNT)) - DOUBLE(MIN(REFCNT)))*1000,1) AS PERWGT FROM AGIF.POP3750 WHERE WDATE =#{wdate} AND MACHCD = #{machcd} AND "POSITION" = 'O' GROUP BY PRDDATE, SUBSTR(PRDTIME,1,3) ORDER BY PRDDATE, SUBSTR(PRDTIME,1,3) ) B ON A.PRDDATE = B.PRDDATE AND A.PRDTIM = B.PRDTIM ORDER BY A.PRDDATE,A.PRDTIM
```

This is my code currently. The database currently stores information by 1 minute intervals. I used SUBSTR to group the data into 10 minute intervals. However, I think that when it is being grouped, it is not including a line of data. For example, if 7:00 - 7:10 is grouped, when 7:10 - 7:20 is grouped, it should include 7:10 in the grouping, but is grouping from 7:11 - 7:20. Any suggestions on how to include that line of data, or another way of grouping by time intervals?

```
CREATE TABLE AGIF.POP3750 (
PRDDATE CHAR(8) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
PRDTIME CHAR(6) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
MACHCD CHAR(6) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
DST_FLAG CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
"POSITION" CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
WDATE CHAR(8) DEFAULT NULL,
WSHT CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
REFCNT NUMERIC(6,0) DEFAULT NULL,
WEIGHT CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
UPLOAD CHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: It's better provide some abstract sample data and the result desired, than providing such a long statement...

Comment: So you're saying that the `7:10` should be included in both `7:00 - 7:10` and `7:10 - 7:20`?

Comment: @GSerg yes, but it is being omitted

Comment: @MarkBarinstein so the PRDCNT should be 31 for 7:00 - 7:10, but it is showing up as 28

Comment: @DanielLee I believe that nobody will try to guess how you store your date & time values, why you use `SUBSTR(PRDTIME, 1, 3)` for grouping, what you mean as "line of data", etc, just looking at your very long statement. Once again, show your sample data (it's better along with exact `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements), and the result desired.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein CREATE TABLE AGIF.POP3750 (
 PRDDATE CHAR(8) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
 PRDTIME CHAR(6) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
 MACHCD CHAR(6) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
 DST_FLAG CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
 "POSITION" CHAR(1) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL,
 WDATE CHAR(8) DEFAULT NULL,
 WSHT CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 REFCNT NUMERIC(6,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 WEIGHT CHAR(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 UPLOAD CHAR(14) DEFAULT NULL
);

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Added create table statement and sample data

Comment: Please edit the question. You appear to have supplied a table definition, but we also need some sample data that replicates the problem

Comment: @Used_By_Already I did edit the question

Comment: Without sample data nothing concrete can be offered. Thats why your wuestion is attracting closure votes. Add the sample data into the question don't use comments for this. Ideally the data is in the form of  inserts or easily parsed text.

Comment: @Used_By_Already I posted a screenshot of some data in the question. I don't have a insert statement because I didn't create the database, and the data is automatically retrieved from a server and put into the database.

Comment: A picture of data? Seriously? You expect volunteers that provide answers to your problem to transcribe that into a usable form. How much would you enjoy a picture of a complex SQL solution that you ned transcribe?

Comment: ... You realize that by including `7:10` data in **two** buckets your report is going to be giving (at minimum) misleading results, right?  If we assume that the data range nominally starts at midnight, you should probably be truncating data for the bucket grouping, meaning it should appear in only the `7:10 - 7:19` bucket (the previous bucket being `7:00 - 7:09`, and the next bucket being `7:20 - 7:29`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse That's what the result set is already doing, and it is already giving misleading results for the result data I need. I need that data to be included in two buckets. I work at a tire plant so the next day starts based on shifts, not on midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GRP, COUNT(1) CNT
FROM
(
SELECT 
  T.V_TRUNCATED - (CASE V.I WHEN 2 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) MINUTES GRP
, T.V
FROM
(
SELECT V, V - 60*MOD(MINUTE(V), 10) - SECOND(V) V_TRUNCATED
FROM 
(
VALUES 
  TIME('07.00.00')
, TIME('07.05.00')
, TIME('07.10.00')
, TIME('07.15.00')
, TIME('07.18.00')
, TIME('07.20.00')
) T (V)
) T, (VALUES 1, 2) V(I)
WHERE V.I=1 OR V.I=2 AND T.V = T.V_TRUNCATED
)
GROUP BY GRP;

|GRP     |CNT        |
|--------|-----------|
|06:50:00|1          |
|07:00:00|3          |
|07:10:00|4          |
|07:20:00|1          |
```

Here is an idea how to do this on sample data. You may run it as is, add / change the values to check if it's suitable for you.
Brief description of what happens here.
First of all, we compute the `V_TRUNCATED` column for each row - time truncated to tens of minutes.
Secondly, if you want some row to be computed in different groups according to your requirements, then you must "copy" this row. This is why we cross-join our initial set of rows with a virtual table of 2 rows. The row is copied, if the actual time value is equal to its truncated one only.
Finally, the grouping expression is calculated as follows: if it's not copied row, then leave it as is, and if it's copied one, then subtract 10 minutes from it (to make it come to a previous group).

If such an algorithm is not suitable for you, then provide the result desired on my sample data.

Comment: Thank you. I will play with this sample and see if it works.